# Tasks with new Devart backed DbContexts raise errors

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, db2, task, devart

I have been pulling my hair on this one for a while now:

When i use the DbContext backed by the Devart DB2 provider in several tasks i get a `NullReferenceException` with the following stacktrace:

```
at Devart.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection.Clear()
at Devart.Data.DB2.Entity.v.g()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CloneDbCommand(DbCommand fromDbCommand)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbCommandDefinition.CreateCommand()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.PrepareEntityCommandBeforeExecution(EntityCommand entityCommand)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I do spawn several new Contexts, but using the same login to one database, with each method started with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and they all start colliding with the error above.
I checked the contexts created and they all get a new id so i'm not reusing the same one in any way.

When i run them in order, one after the other, no problem.
Even when i run other in parallel with another login, no problem.

Have anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

This was casued by a bug in the dotConnect for DB2 by Devart

It was fixed 11th of feb 2016, but took a long time until i realized that thanks to the lack of nuget support by Devart :(

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/db2/revision_history.html